# How To Display Multiple Model Data Into Single Html Table In View Using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

These Are Two Model

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Now How to Display Both Model Data Into Single Html Table Inside View,Using ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

use model.addattribute("obj1_key", you_object1) and so on, your handler method must return new ModelAndView("your_page_name"). in your jsp page you can use EL to display them as follow ${obj1_key}...